# In Asterisk, should I worry about reloading configuration files during calls?

Tags: asterisk, ivr

I have a small application that reads the extensions, peers voicemail info etc from an Excel file and generates what Asterisk understands: sip.conf, extensions.conf, voicemail.conf, etc...

Once its done generating the configuration files it reloads them by executing:

```
sip reload
dialplan reload
voicemail reload
moh reload
// etc...
```

Is it safe to reload all this while I am using the system? For example if someone is in a call and I reload all those configuration files can a problem occur? Should I wait for all the calls to finish and then reload all the configuration files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reload anytime you want, it even will switch execution of dialplan in middle if you change&reload that part of dialplan.

Only thing you should worry - not reload LARGE config files(10k+ lines) faster then it able finish config parsing.